# CakePHP update public $uses = false; in action from same Controller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I'm writing an installation script for my CakePHP web application. I have a `InstallController` with 6 actions: `step1`, `step2`, `step3`, etc.

At `step1` I'm handling `Config/database.php` creation. Because this file is empty and no datasource is available I have to set `public $uses = false;` in the `InstallController`.

At `step2` the `Config/database.php` file is set so I should be able to make a connection to the datasource. This is also necessary because I want to update some database fields in the following steps.

Is it possible to update the `public $uses = false;` in every following steps after `step1`?

I'm using CakePHP version 2.3.5

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version and tag your question accordingly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered loading the model within the actions? So, something like:

```
<?php

App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class InstallController extends AppController {
    public $uses = false;

    public function step1() {

    }

    public function step2() {
        $this->loadModel("Install");
        $this->Install->callMethod();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In CakePHP 2.x models are lazy loaded, so as long as your `step1` action doesn't try to make use of a model, you can safely declare the models in your controllers `$uses` property, they are not being constructed until your code actually makes use of them.

However, if for some reason you'd actually need to modify `$uses`, well then just do it, as mentioned models are lazy loaded, so you can modify `$uses` whenever you want and then access the models afterwards via magic properties on the controller.

Comment: When I use `public $uses = array('Install');` I get a datasource error. Roosevelt's solution works for me. Thanks for the info though!